# What is the purpose of Ref-qualified member functions ?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-qualifier, ref-qualifier

While reading http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions, I came across something, I haven't seen before: `lvalue/rvalue Ref-qualified member functions`. What would be their purpose ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just read down below:

> During overload resolution, non-static cv-qualified member function of class X is treated as a function that takes an implicit parameter of type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X if it has no ref-qualifiers or if it has the lvalue ref-qualifier. Otherwise (if it has rvalue ref-qualifier), it is treated as a function taking an implicit parameter of type rvalue reference to cv-qualified X.

## Example

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
    void f() & { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; }
    void f() &&{ std::cout << "rvalue\n"; }
};
 
int main(){
    S s;
    s.f();            // prints "lvalue"
    std::move(s).f(); // prints "rvalue"
    S().f();          // prints "rvalue"
}
```

So during overload resolution the compiler looks for the function &-qualified if the caller object is an `lvalue` or for the function &&-qualified if the caller object is an `rvalue`.

Comment: How much better a place this world would become if all the inhuman standardese was augmented with a clear and concise example!

Comment: I can't test with C++98. Is this after C++11 ?

Comment: @Nick, yes it is

Comment: @sunnymoon Could you please explain the quotation in simple words for me?

Comment: @John Basically, you can overload class or struct member functions on the basis of what an instance of that class will be - an lvalue (locator-value, think _'named'_, _'long-lived'_ or _'located at some named area of memory in stack or heap'_) or rvalue (i.e. non-locator-value, think _'anonymous'_, _'temporary'_ or _'located at a temporary memory area, maybe a processor register_'). That's why an lvalue `S`'s `f()` prints `"lvalue"` and rvalue `S`'s `f()` prints `"rvalue"`. Ref-qualifiers are those `&` (lvalue) and `&&` (rvalue) after `void f()`.

Comment: The ref-qualified member selected is based on whether 'this' in the function is an lvalue or an rvalue. The use of the technical term "caller object" means "this".