# Make ++o++ complain for types with user defined pre- and postfix increment operators

Tags: c++, post-increment, prvalue, least-astonishment

I'm looking for a way to prevent `++x++` from working for types with user defined prefix and postfix increment operators.

For builtin types the result type of the postfix operator is not an lvalue but a prvalue expression and the compilers complain nicely.

The simplest thing i can think of is to return const for the postfix increment operator:

```
struct S {
    int i_;
    S& operator++() {
        ++i_;
        return *this;
    }
    S /*const*/ operator++(int) {
        S result(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return result;
    }
};
int main() {
    S s2{0};
    ++s2++;
}
```

[Here's a godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4qhqTr4ao).

Is this approach flawed?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the answers, i found more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002799/what-does-the-ampersand-at-the-end-of-member-function-signature-mean), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474374/what-is-the-purpose-of-ref-qualified-member-functions) and of course on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions).

Comment: Returning const classes by value in general is flawed - it inhibits moving from such values. (And on non-class types returned by value the constness is ignored completely.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want `S& operator++() &` and `S operator++(int) &`.  You're missing the `&` at the end that makes the operators only work on lvalues.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to make the prefix `++` operator work only on lvalues.

This syntax works since C++11.

```
S& operator++() & {
//              ^ This & allows only lvalues for *this
    ++i_;
    return *this;
}
```

[Here's a godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fdoPPo8oh).

Comment: I accepted Mooing Ducks answer because his was a little quicker and mentions to apply the & for pre- and postfix increment operators. On the other hand, i like the additional mention of the history in your answer.