# How to omit the empty arguments in fmt::format?

Tags: c++, string-formatting, c++20, fmt

Is there a way to omit the empty string literals (`""`) in the argument list of the `fmt::format` function?

I have the below snippet which gives the desired output:

```
#include <string>
#include <fmt/core.h>


int main( )
{
    const std::string application_layer_text_head { fmt::format( "{:*<5}[Application Layer]{:*<51}\n\n", "", "" ) };
    fmt::print( "{}", application_layer_text_head );
}
```

Output:

```
*****[Application Layer]***************************************************
```

So instead of writing this: `fmt::format( "{:*<5}[Application Layer]{:*<51}\n\n", "", "" )` can we remove the empty literals and write this: `fmt::format( "{:*<5}[Application Layer]{:*<51}\n\n" )`? I tried it but it failed to compile. Those two literals don't really serve any purpose so I want to find a way to not write them.

Just to clarify, I only want to have 5 `*` in the beginning and then `[Application Layer]` and then 51 `*` and then 2 `\n`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I don't only want 5 `*`. Look at the output text. That's what I want. And `fmt::format` works well in this case and is far more efficient than the `operator+` of `std::string`. So it makes sense to use it.

Comment: It's more efficient than `operator+`, but `operator+=` and `append` avoids most of those costs (reallocating in place, rather than constructing new `string`s and discarding old ones, and `reserve` can be used to ensure it's a single allocation if you really need it).

Comment: I think the question here really is "How do I format this string with 5 `*`s on the left and 51 `*`s on the right?", rather than "how to omit the empty arguments?" Or even more generally: what's the best way of formatting the character `c` `n` times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted already, `format` can't do this. But your worries about string concatenation being expensive are misplaced; repeated application of `operator+` is expensive (performs new allocations, copies all existing data and new data, discards old data, over and over), but in-place concatenation with `operator+=` and `append` is cheap, especially if you pre-`reserve` (so you're allocating once up-front and populating, not relying on amortized growth patterns in reallocation to save you). Even without pre-`reserve`, `std::string` follows amortized growth patterns, so repeated in-place concatenation is amortized `O(1)` (per character added), not `O(n)` in the size of the data so far.

The following should be, essentially by definition, at least as fast as formatting, though at the expense of a larger number of lines of code to perform the pre-`reserve` to prevent reallocation:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <fmt/core.h>

using namespace std::literals;

int main( )
{
    // Make empty string, and reserve enough space for final form
    auto application_layer_text_head = std::string();
    application_layer_text_head.reserve(5 + "[Application Layer]"sv.size() + 51 + "\n\n"sv.size());

    // append is in-place, returning reference to original string, so it can be chained
    // Using string_view literals to avoid need for any temporary runtime allocated strings,
    // while still allowing append to use known length concatenation to save scanning for NUL
    application_layer_text_head.append(5, '*').append("[Application Layer]"sv).append(51, '*').append("\n\n"sv);
    fmt::print("{}", application_layer_text_head);
}
```

If you were okay with some of the concatenations potentially performing reallocation, and a final move construction to move the resources from the temporary reference to a real string, it simplifies to a one-liner:

```
const auto application_layer_text_head = std::move(std::string(5, '*').append("[Application Layer]"sv).append(51, '*').append("\n\n"sv));
```

or, given that 5 asterisks is short enough to type, the even shorter/simpler version:

```
const auto application_layer_text_head = std::move("*****[Application Layer]"s.append(51, '*').append("\n\n"sv));
```

But keeping it to a two-liner avoids the move construction and is a little safer:

```
auto application_layer_text_head = "*****[Application Layer]"s;
application_layer_text_head.append(51, '*').append("\n\n"sv);
```

Yeah, none of those are quite as pretty as a single format literal, even with "ugly" empty placeholders. If you prefer the look of the format string, just pass along the empty placeholders the way you're already doing.

Comment: Your one liner constructs a string and then copies it, plus is pretty open to dangling (if you wrote `auto const&` or `auto&&` instead).

Comment: @Barry: Hmm... You're probably right, since it returns by reference, not value; I suppose `std::move` could be used to at least make it a move construct, and while I can't imagine why you'd declare it a reference directly, it would be a problem if you tried to inline it in a method call that received it by (dangling) reference. So yeah, probably best to two-line it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. And speaking of dangling references does it really happen in `const auto application_layer_text_head = std::string(5, '*').append("[Application Layer]"sv).`? Isn't it going to do a move construction cause the object on the right side is temporary (rvalue)?

Comment: @digito_evo The right hand side isn't an rvalue, it's an lvalue.

Comment: @Barry But why? It's a value without any identifier. How could it be an lvalue?

Comment: @digito_evo Because identifiers aren't the only things that are lvalues. `string::append()`  returns an lvalue reference.

Comment: @digito_evo: The reason it behaves this way is that it is modifying the str in-place, to avoid copies, and the return value is always an l-value reference to the original str. This allows chaining method calls with no overhead, and doesn't require reassignment when the object already has a name, but it means that, even when you're operating on an r-value initially, it's still returning an l-value reference. They could add [r-value qualified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19474374/364696) versions of `append`, but they have not done so since the feature was added in C++11. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 4):

Formatting markup is meant for formatting a string with some piece of user-provided data. The particulars of the specialized syntax within formatting can adjust how this formatting works, even inserting characters and the like. But this functionality is meant to be a supplement to the basic act: taking some user-provided object and injecting it into a string.

So no, `format` doesn't have a mechanism to allow you to avoid providing the user-provided data that is the entire reason `format` exists in the first place.

It should also be noted that the very meaning of the text after the `:` in a format specifier is defined based on the type of the object being formatted. The "*<5" means "align to 5 characters using '*' characters to fill in the blanks" *only because* you provided a string for that particular format parameter. So not only does `format` not provide a way to do this, it functionally *cannot*. You have to tell it what type is being used because this is an integral part of processing what "*<5" means.

Comment: So is there another better (cleaner) way to do this? I chose format because it's performant.

Comment: @digito_evo you can create a custom type and write custom formatting rules for it.